# How to make a navbar in php

Tags: php, html, web, navbar

So I've been wondering on how I can link pages together and using php came up.

So how do I make a navbar in php and then include it in html; and how would I stylize the navbar after I include it inside the html.

Comment: You make navbar for a webpage using html,css, javascript...., not PHP.

Comment: find a tutorial. this is a site for a very specific case. :) try using css bootstrap framework.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I know how to make a navbar but I don't know how to link it to multiple pages

Comment: What exactly do you mean "link it to multiple pages"? Do you want to see the same navigation bar in every page?

Answer (score 0):

Including a php file inside another file is as simple as putting

```
<?php 
    include "somenavbarfile.php";
?>
```

at the exact place you want to insert the code for the navigation. Stylizing the navigation bar can be done by assigning class names to certain elements inside the navigation, and using CSS to style them.

And as the others said: creating the navbar itself is basic HTML (and CSS, JavaScript) stuff.

Comment: I know how to make a navbar but I just do not know how I could make the same navbar in multiple html pages without copying and pasting them into every html page I make.

Comment: Well, as I said :) Create your navbar, put it in a file called navbar.php, and include it inside all the other pages (just after the body tag, probably) with the code snippet I provided.